# Ayuda con carga tabla de SELECT e INSERTAR datos para mostrar en una tabla PHP MYSQL!

Tags: php, mysql, select

Soy nuevo por estos lados encontre su página por la WEB y deseo una manito para este sistema que estoy haciendo, ya que mi pericia con la programación y el desarrollo web es realmente básica y estoy en proceso de aún perfeccionarme y aprender más.

Voy al grano, el problema que tengo es que mediante un formulario de registro tengo solamente textbox para añadir datos. La cosa es que me pidieron agregar un select dinamico y se me olvido como poder instaurarlo dentro de mi mantenedor. Sin embargo cree los campos y una tabla que va relacionada con otra para poder hacer referencias y mostrar los datos que salen ahi, el drama es no se mostrar el select y hacer que se vea en una lista. Añadire los formularios y la base de datos.

---

**Base de Datos**

```
use master;

create database intranet;

use intranet;

create table cargo(
cod_cargo int (5)  PRIMARY KEY,
nom_cargo varchar(30),
foreign key (cod_cargo) REFERENCES usuarios(cod_cargo)
);

insert into cargo values ('1','Secretaria Alcaldia');
insert into cargo values ('2','Jefe de Gabinete');
insert into cargo values ('3','Secretaria de Administracion');
insert into cargo values ('4','Encargado de Informatica');
insert into cargo values ('5','Oficina de Partes');
insert into cargo values ('6','Encargada de OIRS');

drop table cargo;

create table usuarios(
usuario varchar(45) PRIMARY KEY,
clave varchar(45) NOT NULL,
cod_cargo int (5) NOT NULL,
cargo varchar (45) NOT NULL,
admin boolean NOT NULL,
foreign key (cod_cargo) references cargo (cod_cargo)
);

insert into usuarios values
('Admin','123456','1','Administrador',1);

drop table usuarios;
```

---

**Formulario de registro con código HTML**, acá es donde ingreso los datos, supuestamente tengo que añadir un SELECT abajo del Textbox clave y reemplazar el que está ahí.

```
<?php 
require '../scripts/funciones.php';
if(! haIniciadoSesion() || ! esAdmin() )
{
header('Location: index.html');
}

conectar();
$usuarios = getUsuario();
desconectar();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Panel de Administración</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->

    <link href="../css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Validaciones en JavaScript -->

    <script src="validar-usuario.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- CSS ME -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <?php include './menu-superior.php'; ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <?php include './sidebar.php'; ?>

        <!-- <?php include './menu-lateral.php'; ?> -->

        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" >

        <h1 class="page-header">Agregar Nuevo Usuario:</h1>

        <form action="registro.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validar();">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Usuario:</label>
<input style="width: 20%;" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtUsuario" name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Ingrese Usuario" required="required"  >
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Clave:</label>
<input style="width: 20%;" type="password" class="form-control" id="txtClave" name="txtClave" placeholder="Ingrese Clave"required="required"   >
        </div>

    <label for="pwd">Cargo:</label>
    <br>
    <select style="width: 20%;" name="cargo" size="0">
      <?php
       while ($arreglo = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {   ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $arreglo ['cod_cargo']?>"><?php echo $arreglo['nom_cargo']?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">N° de Permiso (1 para admin y 0 para usuario):</label>
      <br>
     <input style="width: 20%;" type="number" class="form-control" id="txtAdmin" name="txtAdmin" placeholder="Ingrese N° de Permiso"required="required"> 

<hr>

<button type="submit" id="btnguardar" name="btnguardar" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>

<input type="reset" name="btn-reset" value="Limpiar Campos" class="btn btn-primary">

        </form>

       </div>

       <?php
       if(isset($_POST['btnguardar'])){
        require("registro.php");

        }
       ?>

    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Registro PHP**, página en donde inserto los datos.

```
<?php


$conexion;

require '../scripts/funciones.php';

conectar();

// CREACION DE VARIABLES $USUARIO, $CLAVE, $CARGO Y $PERMISO PARA ALMACENAR LOS DATOS

$usuario = $_POST['txtUsuario'];
$clave = $_POST['txtClave'];
$cargo = $_POST['txtCargo'];
$permiso = $_POST['txtAdmin'];

// CONSULTA PARA INSERTAR LOS DATOS RECOGIDOS EN LAS VARIABLES DENTRO DEL FORMULARIO

$insertar = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES('".$usuario."', '".$clave."', '".$cargo."', '".$permiso."')");

// EJECUCION DE CONSULTA

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar); 

// IF PARA VERIFICAR SI EL USUARIO SE REGISTRO O NO, DE LO CONTRARIO INGRESE NUEVAMENTE LOS DATOS

if(!$resultado){
echo'<script>alert("Usuario registrado satisfactoriamente!")</script>';
echo'<script>alert("Ahora elija los permisos para el usuario.")</script>';
echo '<script>location.href ="permisos.php"</script>';
}else
{
echo '<script>alert("Error, Usuario no Registrado.")</script>';
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

---

Seria de mucha ayuda si logran ayudarme, les agradeceria un montón muchos saludos a todos desde Chile.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende del todo. Dices que en el HTML debes mostrar un `select` debajo del textbox clave *y reemplazar el que está ahí*. Pero resulta que no hay ningún `select` que reemplazar. Tampoco explicas si ese `select` debe ser escrito a manos ni con qué datos, o si debe leer alguna tabla de la base de datos y mostrar los registros de esa tabla en el `select`. Y si así fuera, tampoco explicas cómo se relacionan las consultas de tu tabla con el HTML. Sin esos detalles es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: el select ya fue puesto en registrar.php, ese boton esta pensado para leer la tabla cargo. y imprimir el nom_cargo. no se si me expique bien

Comment: No, no te has explicado bien. No veo ningún select en `registrar.php`. Cuando planteas un problema debes explicar con toda claridad el estado de las cosas, cómo funcionan, como se relacionan, que hace cada cosa. Es tu programa, los otros no lo han escrito, no lo entienden y por tanto eres tú quién debe explicar la lógica que sigue el programa. Cuando hay dificultad de parte del programador para explicar la lógica de su programa esa es muchas veces la principal fuente de los demás problemas.

Comment: estimado, abajo del label clave esta mi select hice el ciclo while segun me acordaba lo que pasa es que no logro que me liste. fijate bien en registrar.php

Comment: Ohhh, perdón, eso debe ser nuevo, no lo había visto antes. Ahí tienes un problema, estás usando una función obsoleta y posiblemente mezclando con `mysqli`, pues tienes esto: `while ($arreglo = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {` y deberías usar `mysqli`, algo así: `while ($arreglo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {`  prueba a corregir eso y comenta lo que pasa.

Comment: en efecto era eso, muchas gracias por su ayuda logre solucionar el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un problema en la parte donde construyes el `select`, pues haces una mezcla de la API `mysql_` (obsoleta) con la API `mysqli_` (que usas, y así deber ser, en el resto del código, menos aquí).

Debes por tanto usar `mysqli` también ahí:

```
<select style="width: 20%;" name="cargo" size="0">
  <?php while ($arreglo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $arreglo ['cod_cargo']?>"><?php echo $arreglo['nom_cargo']?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

---

**NOTA.SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**

Tu consulta `INSERT` es altamente vulnerable a ataques de **inyección SQL**. Deberías aplicar consultas preparadas para corregir ese agujero de seguridad en el código.

En una edición posterior de esta respuesta podría indicar la forma de hacerlo, si te interesa.

Answer (score 0):

en el insert al parecer falta un dato

en la tabla usuaros

```
usuario varchar(45) PRIMARY KEY,
clave varchar(45) NOT NULL,
cod_cargo int (5) NOT NULL,
cargo varchar (45) NOT NULL,
admin boolean NOT NULL,
```

son 5 registros y en el select solo pones 4

```
$insertar = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES('".$usuario."', '".$clave."', '".$cargo."', '".$permiso."')");
```

si quieres poner solo esos 4 debes de especificarlo en el INSERT

```
$insertar = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario,clave,cod_cargo,admin) VALUES('".$usuario."', '".$clave."', '".$cargo."', '".$permiso."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

entiendo perfectamente tu punto, lo que quiero hacer es la secuencia completa del SELECT . no se si te diste cuenta pero la tabla cargo posee un campo nombre cargo ese mismo quiero plasmarlo en mi tabla para asi mostrar los registros de usuario junto a ese campo. en eso justamente es donde estoy topando :/